# Printing out dymanic html table (jquery datatable plugin) using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, database

Ok so I have been on this problem for quite some time now and have thoroughly researched it.  First of all I am using Spring Tool Suite - MVC Project.  Working on a .jsp page

I am trying to figure out the best/proper/efficient way to dynamically create and edit a HTML table that will be linked to a dataTables (jQuery plugin) table based on data from a MySql database.

I want the user to be able to update the tables based on different user input....buttons, price range inputs, ect.

So far the best way I have researched is to wrap the creation of the table inside a js function and then create other functions that will alter the table, add to it, update it, or anything else I want to  do.  I am having no luck creating a datatable using a function as of now the best I can do is use java to connect to my databsae and create a SINLGE table that successfully loads and displays the data from the database, the problem is I cannot alter the table after the page has loaded, every attempt on a table refresh based on a new sql query has failed.

Datatables has a pretty large api which I was able to use to add a row to the table, but other functions that would appear to be useful, like updating the tables does not work.

This got me thinking if my approach should be completely rethought. What approach should I take?

I will post code if needed

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> aaList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
 ResultSet rs;
     Statement statement = null;
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ics321instance.cglh44ydeyny.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/ics321", "user", "password");
     statement = conn.createStatement();
     //this query should return all items
     rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from Product where price < 10;");

     int counter=1;
     ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
     %>

    <table id = "example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <%
            for(int q = 1; q<=metaData.getColumnCount();q++)
            {%>
                <th><%= metaData.getColumnName(q)%></th>
            <%
            }
            %>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <%
            while(rs.next())
            {
            %>
                <tr>
                 <%
                 for(int i = 1; i<=metaData.getColumnCount();i++)
                 {%>
                    <td><%= rs.getString(i)%></td>
                 <% 
                 }
                 %> 
                </tr>                  
            <% 
             }
             %>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So here I am making a connection to the db and executing the query in the jsp - I know this is bad practice but I cant figure out any other way

up in the header I have my js

```
$(function() {
     $("#example").dataTable({
       "sScrollY": "400px",
       "bPaginate": false,
       "bScrollCollapse": true 
     });
}
```

I think the right way to do it would be using the JDBCTemplate inside of my controller - but I am unsure how to reference that data inside of my .jsp file.

Again my goal is to have a table (datatables jquery plugin) and have that table update based on the user interaction with the jsp page, buttons, text input, ect.

There is a method insude of the datatables api - fnDraw() which is supposed to redraw the table but I do not know where to put the function.

Thank you